# if flag = 0, then which will be the most preferable statement to execute the true or false block? if(!flag) or if(flag == 0)

Tags: c, if-statement

In the code given here:

```
void search(int a)
{
    int i = 0, flag = 1;
    for(; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if(a == stack[i])
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!flag)
        printf("%d found at location %d.\n", a, i);
    else
        printf("%d not found in the stack.\n", a);
    return;
}
```

which statement `if(!flag) or if(flag == 0)` will be more efficient and generalized?
Is using `if(!flag)` considered as a wrong approach?

Comment: Any sane compiler will most likely emit the exact same machine code for both expressions. So you don't need to worry about this. Use what you think is more readable, I'd vote for `!flag`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Does this code have anything to do with the code optimization? I mean those two statements.

Comment: If it being 0 has meaning beyond "false", then use == 0. Otherwise, use !. That's my usual.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about optimisation. Roughly spoken: the compiler tries to generate the most efficient code (at least with optimisation flags enabled), but this case is so simple that most sane compilers will probably optimise this condition to the most efficient machine code even without using optimisation flags.

Comment: Putnam's right - if you're treating `flag` as a Boolean, then `!flag` is more idiomatic than `flag == 0`.  There will be no effective difference between the two in performance; they will very likely result in the same machine code.

Comment: @JohnBode Yes I'm treating that as a boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are almost no technical differences between the two versions:

- `!` integer promotes its operand and returns an `int`, `1` or `0`.
- `==` balances both operands according to usual arithmetic conversions (including integer promotion), then returns an `int`, `1` or `0`.

In most cases you'll get identical machine code. So this is mostly a matter of coding style and therefore subjective.

As a rule of thumb, whatever you pass to `if` should be regarded as if it was a boolean type. C doesn't have integrated boolean types in the language, hence the above operators return `int` and not `bool`, which would make more sense and how C++ works. C uses `int` for backwards-compatibility reasons.

We can however write C code *as if* the language had proper boolean integration - pretend that it does. That's a stance recommended by various coding standards like MISRA-C. But in this specific case, that wouldn't affect the code either. You could swap your `flag` for standard C `bool` with value `true`/`false`, but it would still be fine to use either `!flag` or `flag==false`.

For the sake of readability alone, I'd rewrite your example to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void search (int key)
{
    bool found = false;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<MAX && !found; i++)
    {
        if(key == stack[i])
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(found)
        printf("%d found at location %d.\n", key, i);
    else
        printf("%d not found in the stack.\n", key);
}
```

The resulting machine code should be identical. The main readability issue was the lack of meaningful variable names.

Comment: "C doesn't have integrated boolean types in the language" --> border line correct/wrong since C99 and `_Bool`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Read the whole part where I wrote that: the context is what's returned from various "logical" operators. C++ returns an actual boolean type, since somewhere around the 1980s. While this remains a language flaw in C.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you. You explained it very well and it's great how you made the code more readable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica There's also this: https://godbolt.org/z/b4dMoY. Amuse yourself by changing from -O0 to -O3 and back.

Comment: And also `_Generic( !(_Bool){true}, _Bool: puts("_Bool is _Bool"), default: puts("_Bool_is not _Bool") );` which further demonstrates just how broken the language is.

Comment: @Lundin Usage of `sizeof true` (or any other numerical literal) is not recommended anyway. If it was `sizeof b` it would have been fine.